# Last Digit of Multiplications

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

I have 4 different 1 digit positive integer numbers $(a,b,c,d)$.

than I apply this formula

$random(a,b,c,d) × random(a,b,c,d) × ... × random(a,b,c,d)$

the last digit of the result is always one of the numbers

What numbers do I have ?

Note :

- $random(a,b,c,d)$ means take 1 random number between a,b,c, or d
- You can do the multiplications as long as you like.
- There are more than 1 solutions

Comment: Are we allowed to use a computer if we wish as an extra answer to be posted later on after giving everyone a chance to try it out for a while? I think there is probably a general rule here. Also, is 0 allowed? That would be a pretty trivial case.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : To make sure the answers are complete, you can do that, but I have checked it by computer, and no more answer if 0 is not allowed. There are 7 answers if 0 is allowed.

Comment: The answers if 0 is allowed are : [0,1,4,6], [0,1,5,6], [0,1,5,9], [0,4,5,6], [1,3,7,9], [1,4,6,9], [2,4,6,8]

Comment: oh yeah, you're right. For some reason I thought the inclusion of 0 would make every product = 0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution 1:

> $2,4,6,8$

.

> ```
>  * | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8
>
>  2 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 6
>
>  4 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 2
>
>  6 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8
>
>  8 | 6 | 2 | 8 | 4
> ```

Solution 2:

> $1,3,7,9$

.

> ```
>  * | 1 | 3 | 7 | 9
>
>  1 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 9
>
>  3 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 7
>
>  7 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 3
>
>  9 | 9 | 7 | 3 | 1
> ```

Answer (score 16):

How about a third solution, in addition to the two provided by Marius and M Oehm:

Solution 3:

> $1, 4, 6, 9$

.

> ```
>  0 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 9
>  1 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 9 
>  4 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 6 
>  6 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 4 
>  9 | 9 | 6 | 4 | 1
> ```

As previous answers:

Solution 1:

> $2,4,6,8$

Solution 2:

> $1,3,7,9$

Answer (score 12):

Other answers have established that there is at least one other solution besides the two intended by the original questioner. Let's determine rigorously what all the solutions are.

> If any of the numbers is a 2, then we must also have $2\times2=4$ and similarly 8 and 6. Similarly if any of them is an 8. Therefore, *if we have a 2 or an 8 then we have {2,4,6,8}*.
>
>  If any of the numbers is a 3, then we must also have $3\times3=9$, hence 7, hence 1. Similarly if any of them is a 7. Therefore, *if we have a 3 or a 7 then we have {1,3,7,9}*.
>
>  If neither of those conditions holds then the numbers we have are a subset of {1,4,5,6,9}. It is easy to verify that *{1,4,6,9} is a solution*. Are there others?
>
>  If so, they must contain 5 together with exactly three of {4,6,9}. We can't have both 5 and 4, or both 5 and 6, because then we'd need 0 and the numbers have to be positive. So this isn't possible.
>
>  Hence: the possible solutions are in fact exactly the ones already found: {1,3,7,9}, {2,4,6,8}, and {1,4,6,9}. (Odd numbers, even numbers, squares.)

Comment: 6 isn't square, but your point is well taken. :)

Comment: Rubio, 6 is a square *mod 10*. Gareth, yes, I could call them +-1 mod 5, but I think the fact that they're the nonzero squares mod 5 is more fundamental. (We basically need "half" the options, which we can get by picking one of the two options mod 2 or by picking the only index-2 subgroup available mod 5.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer =)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Btw, {1,4,6,9} is not a set containing only squares (which seems to be implied by your last remark), because 6 is not a square. =)

Comment: As I said to Rubio, 6 *is* a square; it's 4 squared. We're working modulo 10 here.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is:

> 2, 4, 6, 8.
>
>  Multiplication of these numbers will always yield an even number, because all numbers are even. It will never yield a number that ends with zero, because none of these numbers has 5 as a prime factor, which is required to get the factor 10.

Marius has already found the second solution:

> 1, 3, 7, 9.
>
>  The reasoning is analogous to the one for the even numbers: Muliplying odd numbers will yield odd numbers. Numbers that end in 5 have a factor of 5, which is coprime to all four numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of solutions

> ... if you allow other bases. Below is one solution in base 16.

.

> 1, 7, 9, f

Answer (score 0):

the answer is

> 2,4,6,8
>  the result will always be pair therefor end in 2,4,6,8

Comment: You should explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no-one came up with this one yet:

Another answer is:

> +0 1 5 9

Because:

> ```
>   * | +0 |  1 |  5 |  9
>  +0 | +0 | +0 | +0 | +0
>   1 | +0 |  1 |  5 |  9
>   5 | +0 |  5 |  5 |  5 
>   9 | +0 |  9 |  5 |  1
> ```

And:

> +0 1 4 6

Because:

> ```
>   * | +0 |  1 |  4 |  6
>  +0 | +0 | +0 | +0 | +0
>   1 | +0 |  1 |  4 |  6
>   4 | +0 |  4 |  6 |  4
>   6 | +0 |  6 |  4 |  6
> ```

Note:

> In response to the (quite correct!) comment that 0 is not positive, I have replaced all occurrences of "0" with "+0", which is a real thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero - slightly tongue in cheek, but technically correct.

Comment: That would work, except the question says *positive* integers.

Comment: I'm not surprised at all that no one came up with this solution till now. Because of what DanRussell said.

Comment: Corrected - see note at the end.

Comment: 0 1 5 6 should also work under that premise

Comment: I'm not sure this even qualifies as a loophole. It's just a desperate try to turn a wrong answer into a snarky wrong answer. The question clearly states "positive integer numbers".